# Picture book about two friends transported into a video game with a magic carpet and a laser sword

Tags: story-identification, books, isekai, illustrated-story

I'm trying to find this old kids' book I read in elementary school in the 90s-early 2000s.

I remember it was about two friends that somehow went into a video game. I recall a magic carpet and a laser sword that ran out of power. The book was a picture book, fully illustrated, and I vaguely recall it side-scrolled in the game.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.